# Is the DefinitelyTyped Project the same at the @types project?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm pretty new to Typescript, and I'm trying to understand the parts that go into it. Is the DefinitelyTyped Project the same at the @types project?, and is @types the latest way to add type definitions to a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the DefinitelyTyped Project the same at the @types project?

You could say that. A better statement : The NPM modules under @types are automatically published from the type definitions present in the DefinitelyTyped Project.

- The @types org Packages : https://www.npmjs.com/~types
- Definitely Typed files used to generate / publish the packages : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Answer (score 1):

The DefinitelyTyped project predates the @types module scope. Before Typescript 2.1 type definitions had to be maintained manually or via a 3rd party package manager like [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings). To simplify type management the @types module scope was introduced so that NPM could be used to manage type definitions. Typescript 2.1+ automatically checks for installed @types modules includes them during compilation.

[This article answers this question and others related to typescript and the @types module scope.](https://blog.angular-university.io/typescript-2-type-system-how-do-type-definitions-work-in-npm-when-to-use-types-and-why-what-are-compiler-opt-in-types/)